# Retrieve images against a word using Angulajs or Nodejs like Google Search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, google-search

I want to retrieve images using AngularJs or Nodejs, but how can I achieve this?

Example: I created a simple search button with HTML, CSS and AngularJs.
I am using Simple Angular Http GET Method:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '?????'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
});
```

So  what URL I can use to get images of that search parameter so that I can download to my server?

Comment: Find an api that gives images links in return of a query.

Comment: Before this gets closed for being off topic, have a look at Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) which supports image searches.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a image search tool.

I would suggest you to follow following steps:
1. Make a Database which contains mapping of image with keywords.
2. Make an Web API, which gets image names from DB as per the keyword entered.(This will require backend technology such as nodejs or ASP.Net Web API)
3. Return those image URLs and render it on UI.

To make your search better, you can suggest users to use some keywords that you are using.

Just for an example, someone entered football, and you are using soccer keyword, you can suggest user to change search keyword.

Hope this will help.

Regards